# Proof that quotient group is cyclic and find its generator

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

Let $\varphi: { GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{7}) \to U_{7} } $ homomorphism such that  $\varphi(A) = det(A) $.

Proof that $H = GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{7}) / ker(\varphi)$ is cyclic and find its generator.

My try: from first homomorphism theorem we know that $O(H) = 6$ because $\varphi$ is on $U_{7}$, but I'm not sure how to continue...

How can I prove that the quotient group is cyclic before finding its generator?

Comment: $U_7$ is cyclic because it's a finite multiplicative subgroup of a field.

Comment: Thanks, but why does it mean that the quotient group is cyclic?

Comment: Alternatively, note that a generator is $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ by explicit calculation.

Comment: mmmmm... I wonder...

Comment: @jgon Thanks! but how did you find it? by guessing? Is there an analytic way?

Comment: @NaveTseva It is easy to see that $\varphi$ is surjective. So by the first isomorphism theorem $H \cong U_7$ and then use Saucy O'Path's hint.

Comment: @NaveTseva I did more or less what Anurag A suggests. I used the fact that I knew $3$ generated $U_7$ (which can be found by noticing $2^3=1$, and $3^2=2$ mod 7), and then observed that the determinant of the matrix I suggested is 3. In general the best way to find a generator of the units group when there is one is by guessing, since the probability of finding one is $\phi(\phi(n))/\phi(n)$, which won't be very small if the units group is cyclic.

Comment: AnuragA & jgon Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the first isomorphism theorem $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb{Z}/7\Bbb{Z})/\ker\varphi$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $U_7$. So it suffices to show that $U_7$ is cyclic. The easiest way to prove this depends on your definition of $U_7$.